# Time to form a complete graph from n vertices given that only k vertices can be used at a time

Tags: graphs, greedy-algorithms, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I know this problem is related to the greedy algorithm and max edges incomplete graph but can't come up with a solution.

**Problem**

You are given two numbers n and k:

n >= k

n is the total # of vertices

k is the maximum number of vertices that can form a complete graph per second

There are no edges initially

how many seconds does it take to form a complete graph of n vertices?

Comment: We can't tell you how many seconds that will take, as that is dependent on the specific architecture and other factors that are not stated here.  I don't know what "maximum number of vertices that can form a complete graph per second" means.

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.